# What data types are supported for Ignite when creating a cache?

Tags: types, ignite

Just want to confirm, when creating Ignite cache - only 2 fields are possible:

```
1) Key
2) Value
```

What data types can be set as Key and Value? (I've seen so far: Integer, String and BinaryObject)

Answer (score 1):

There are no special requirements for data types in Ignite like "Class should implement Serializable interface".

Ignite will serialize all data except classes that really shouldn't be serialized like MBeanServer, ClassLoader, Thread or some Ignite classes. These classes either contain calls to Native Methods or their serialization makes no sense.